# Not permitted to view my newly installed phpMyAdmin

Tags: centos, mysql, apache-2.4, subdomain, phpmyadmin

I'm using Google Compute Engine to host a couple applications under one `.dev` domain so SSL is required.

I have Apache installed based from [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-7) and my `/var/www/` directory looks like:

```
- domain.dev/ (currently in use - WordPress site)
  - html/
    - wp-content/
    - index.php
    - ...
  - log/
- database.domain.dev/ (currently unused - I want to access phpMyAdmin by going to this URL)
  - html/
  - log/
- subdomain.domain.dev/ (currently in use - a separate project but still under the same domain)
  - html/
    - css/
    - scripts/
    - index.php
    - ...
  - log/
```

Right now I can visit these three URLS and they work, except of course `database.domain.dev` - it just gives me the default page that shows Apache is working. I'm trying to [install phpMyAdmin on this subdomain](https://centoshelp.org/servers/database/phpmyadmin-on-centos/) but it's not working.

I already have MySQL installed on this server - it's what WordPress is using. I plan to add another database and another user to it that's why I'm trying to install phpMyAdmin as it's easier to manage from there.

SSL is already working since I can see the page that shows Apache is working when I visit the page. The DNS settings have been taken care of from GCP's Cloud DNS.

On my `/etc/httpd/sites-available/database.domain.dev.conf`, I have this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.database.domain.dev
    ServerAlias database.domain.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/database.domain.dev/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/database.domain.dev/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/database.domain.dev/log/requests.log combined
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.database.domain.dev [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =database.domain.dev
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

On my `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf`, I have this:

```
Alias /manage /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

...

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin support@domain.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/database.domain.dev/html
    ServerName database.domain.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

When I visited `https://database.domain.dev/manage` I expected to see phpMyAdmin pop up but I got an error that said I'm not permitted to view the page. When I tried `https://database.domain.dev/bogus` it said, the URL can't be found. So that gives me an idea that the alias is working but I don't know why I don't have access to view the page.